# How can I have a variable (containing a class) change to another class?

Tags: ios, swift, class, type-conversion

I have a game which could either be online or against the AI. I have a class for each which contain the same functions and properties, however they obviously function differently.

```
class Game { ... }
class GameAI: Game { ... }
class GameOnline: Game { ... }
```

In my ViewController I have a variable 'game' which would work whether 'game' was of type GameAI or GameOnline (as function and property names are the same), and changing this game variable would be a really elegant way for everything to work.

Currently the game variable is as follows:

```
var game = GameAI()
```

And when an online game is started I would like to change this to GameOnline as follows:

```
extension MainViewController: OnlineViewControllerDelegate {
    func onlineGameDidStart(player: Int, gameCode: String) {
        game = GameOnline()
    }
}
```

However this is not possible as the variable is already of type 'GameAI'.

Any help would be amazing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare a property or a variable in Swift you declare it like this:

```
var/let propertyName: PropertyType = InitialValue
```

there is a candy where you can omit `PropertyType` which is then implicitly determined by `InitialValue` assuming that initial value can define it.

So you can have

```
var/let propertyName = InitialValue
```

In your case you omitted your property type and Swift decided to use `GameAI` because this is what you passed as initial value.

To fix you either need to explicitly specify your property type or you need to change your initial value. So any of the following should work:

```
var game: Game = GameAI()
var game = GameAI() as Game
```

**As from comments it appears there is some confusion about subclassing.**

It is not enough to just implement methods in subclasses. You also need to define it in base class. Like so:

```
class Game {
    func beginGame() {
        print("A new game started")
    }
}
class GameAI: Game {
    override func beginGame() {
        super.beginGame()
        print("It is an AI game")
    }
}
class GameOnline: Game {
    override func beginGame() {
        super.beginGame()
        print("It is an online game")
    }
}
```

notice that even `Game` implements this method while their subclasses only override methods. A call to `super.beginGame()` is optional. You call it if you want to add functionality (preserving base class logic) otherwise you may just override all logic.

Another approach is to use protocols. Protocols can not be used to create an instance so there is no need for declaring anything in base class. The rest for your case may stay the same:

```
protocol Game {
    func beginGame()
}

class GameAI: Game {
    func beginGame() {
        print("An AI game started")
    }
}

class GameOnline: Game {
    func beginGame() {
        print("An online game started")
    }
}
```

A protocol is basically a blueprint that forces all classes that correspond to your protocol to actually implement that logic. If you try adding another method in this protocol you will get an error that both classes again need to implement this new method.

To give a bit more interesting example with protocol you can play around with following:

```
protocol Game {
    var id: String { get }
    var startTime: Date { get }
    func beginGame()
    
    func gameDescription() -> String
}

extension Game {
    func gameDescription() -> String {
        return "A game with id \(id) started \(Int(Date().timeIntervalSince(startTime))) seconds ago"
    }
}

class GameAI: Game {
    let id: String = UUID().uuidString
    let startTime: Date = .init()
    
    func beginGame() {
        print("AI game with id \(id) is starting")
    }
}

class GameOnline: Game {
    let id: String
    let startTime: Date = .init()
    
    init(id: String) { self.id = id }
    
    func beginGame() {
        print("Online game started with id \(id)")
    }
    
    func gameDescription() -> String {
        return "Overridden game description"
    }
}
```

If you added more code to your game classes I could present a more realistic example.

Comment: I tried this, however I get hundreds of errors 'Value of type 'Game' has no member ...'. I can't see why this doesn't work?

Comment: @JackWeller did you define those methods in your base class and then override them in subclasses?

Comment: @JackWeller I added another section in this answer. Please check if this clears your problem.

Comment: Matic you're an absolute legend, thanks so much.